# VB.NET - StrDup not working as it should?

Tags: vb.net, string

From my understanding, this code:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.StrDup(3, "123")
```

should return `123123123`. Instead it returns `111`, as if it's working with a wrong overload of `StrDup` (one that accepts `char`). If this is by-design, is there any built-in function that would do the same?

Comment: By design, "Only the first character of the expression will be used."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MSDN, [`StrDup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6kzch7a.aspx) picks only the first character, regardless if you specify a `Char` or a `String`:

> Character - Required. Any valid Char, String, or Object expression.
>   Only the first character of the expression will be used. If Character
>   is of type Object, it must contain either a Char or a String value.

The best way to do `StrDup` for strings is this:

```
String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("123", 3))
```

Comment: That's documented even in intellisense and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w37th3kf(v=vs.80).aspx): "Only the first character of the expression will be used..."

Comment: @Tim: Well I was wondering, maybe intellisense did not get updated. Logically, you should not be passing a string, if you know only the first character will be taken. If you do it, maintainability suffers. Regarding syntactic sugar it adds - it is not that hard to get first `Char` of your `String` manually, something like this: `mystring(0)` or `mystring.Chars(0)`, and use that for clarity.

Comment: To be honest, you should not use those old VB functions at all when you're using VB.NET.

Comment: @Tim: Agreed 200%, `StrDup` is something I found by googling and thought it would do the trick.

Comment: Btw, it `StrDup` actually does this: `return new string(Character[0], Number);` (reflected via `ILSpy`). So it's not an _old_ VB function since it uses the [`.NET String constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) which repeats a character n-times. However, then i would use the constructor directly instead or your `Enumerable.Repeat` approach if you need to repeat strings.

Comment: @Tim: I did not have a chance to look under the hood, but `new string(mystring, number)` was the first thing I tried. Fortunately, it does not have a misleading overload that takes a `String`. So it cannot replace `Enumerable.Repeat`.